# method classification after subclassing dict

Tags: python

I create a class that inherits from `dict`

```
class A(dict):
  def ff(self):
    pass
```

when using `dir(A)` and I wrote an implementation to classify the methods to their classes.
I get,

```
{'A': {'__init_subclass__', '__subclasshook__', '__weakref__', 'ff', 'fromkeys'},

 'dict': {'__contains__', '__delitem__', '__eq__', '__ge__', '__getattribute__',
 '__getitem__', '__gt__', '__init__', '__iter__', '__le__', '__len__',
 '__lt__', '__ne__', '__new__', '__repr__', '__setitem__', '__sizeof__',
 'clear', 'copy', 'get', 'items', 'keys', 'pop', 'popitem', 'setdefault',
 'update', 'values'},

 'object': {'__delattr__', '__dir__', '__format__', '__reduce__',
 '__reduce_ex__', '__setattr__', '__str__'}}
```

but why do only, `fromkeys` and a few other methods get classified under `A`?
why did it not classify all methods under `dict` under `A`?

or why did `fromkeys` not get classified under `dict`?

this is the implementation I wrote to classify methods to their classes,
the result above is in `passed`

```
from collections import defaultdict
passed = defaultdict(lambda : defaultdict(set))
failed = defaultdict(set)
passed_ = defaultdict(lambda : defaultdict(set))
failed_ = defaultdict(lambda : defaultdict(set))
a = A
d = dict
combined = {'a': A, 'd': dict}
for key, value in combined.items():
  for method in dir(value):
    try:
      qualname = eval(f'{key}.{method}.__qualname__')
      qualname = qualname.split('.')
      passed[key][qualname[0]].add(qualname[1])
      type_ = type(eval(f'{key}.{method}'))
      passed_[key][type_].add(qualname[1])
    except:
      failed[key].add(method)
      failed_[key][type_].add(method)
```

Comment: What code are you using to classify methods to their classes?

Comment: added the implementation

Comment: `dir` is not a reliable way to get the attributes of an object.

Comment: @chepner - Can you expand on that comment, please?

Comment: `dir` doesn't necessarily return *every* attribute an object has.